# Can JSON starts with '?('

Tags: python, python-requests

I am struggling to make sense of the response that i am getting, the http response i am receiving is as follows,

When i run this:

```
result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

I get a response like this

```
?({\"Makes\":[{\"id\":\"ab\",\"common\":\"0\",\"make_country\":\"Italy\"}
,{\"id\":\"ac\",\"common\":\"0\",\"make_country\":\"UK\"},{\"id\":\"au\",\"make_is_common\":\"1\",\"make_country\":\"USA\"}}]});
```

[image: The problem that has me baffled]

I have it here:

https://repl.it/@DeepeshKrishnan/OverjoyedSmugBackups

Any clue to how to make this JSON, it shows up a string, i feel the problem are the two characters that appear at the very top
? (

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Short answer is no

Comment: Use the `loads` method, not `dumps` to load a string as JSON.

Comment: @blhsing i tried that got this error:     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Exactly. Because the input is not valid JSON.

Comment: Because it is not a valid JSON

Comment: ...so, the place to start is the documentation for the service you're using. Since their responses aren't JSON, hopefully they'll document the format those responses *are* in. (That's assuming, of course, that they aren't already describing the accurate type in the headers; you've looked at the `Content-Type` response header, right? What does it say?)

Comment: Have you tried stripping off the first two characters before using `loads()`?

Comment: @barny, first two *and last two*. That said, that's a very fragile workaround. Better to find formal documentation -- if they're using a syntax that's a substantial subset of JSON, there may be any number of potential other responses that won't be valid JSON, so only handling one observed case isn't going to be sufficient to result in robust code.

Comment: It sure ain’t JSON with those extra characters.

Comment: (Hmm; `?`s are used in some places in YAML syntax, but this isn't one that appears to be formally specified, at least not as of version 1.2, so whatever it is doesn't appear to be YAML either).

Comment: My fix:
x = (result.content.decode())
# print(x)

index = 0
# Slice string to remove character at index 5
if len(x) > index:
    x = x[0 : index : ] + x[index + 1 : :]

if len(x) > index:
    x = x[0 : index : ] + x[index + 1 : :]

x = x[:-2]
# convert into JSON:
y = json.loads(x)

# the result is a JSON string:
print(type(y))
print(y['Makes'])

Comment: Basically i striped the 'illegal characters' and made this dict that works :-)

Comment: See again re: "very fragile workaround".

Comment: I'm not sure how much we can help you here.